# LUIS dialog + Qna Maker Active learning dialog issue

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I coded a LUIS bot that forward some messages to a Qna maker dialog that enable active learning. 
It works perfectly when a question return a single answer, but when it detect multiple answers, it doesn't send any message but execute my Resume func.

This works if I use my QnaMaker like a root dialog.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Here my forward func :

```
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    [LuisIntent("")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        //Récupération du message
        var messageToForward = await activity;
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var faq = new QnADialogWithOverrides();
        //Transfert du message une fois réponse retournée => AfterFAQDialog
        await context.Forward(faq, AfterFAQDialog, messageToForward, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    private async Task AfterFAQDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
```

My Qna Bot :

```
    [Serializable]
    [QnAMaker("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "I don't understand this right now!", 0.50, 5)]
    public class QnADialogWithOverrides : QnAMakerDialog
    {
    }
```

Results :

[image: What I have]

[image: What I want]

Comment: unless you show more code it will be impossible to help you. Add the code to QnADialogWithOverrides please

Comment: You QnADialogWithOverrides is empty. is that ok?

Comment: Yes I just used the Overrides functions for debugging. The active learning doesn't need overrides functions to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [this condition](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMakerDialog.cs#L97) from the [QnAMakerDialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/7f1439a8edd327172586a4fdbd7f0d01d66372d9/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMakerDialog.cs) is not being met and so the dialog [is ending via the default message path](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMakerDialog.cs#L119-L123).

Strange though, that the condition indicates that you don't have answers, but per your screenshot, it seems that might not be the case.

I would try to override the `RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync` to see what's going on, since that method is the one in charge of showing the results (which by default, the behavior is to show just the first answer, as seen [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMakerDialog.cs#L200)).

You can even use the `QnADialogWithOverrides` code from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/QnAMaker/QnABotWithOverrides/Dialogs/QnADialogWithOverrides.cs).

Comment: I overrode `RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync`, this function is not execute when the user ask a question with multiple answers. So, I overrode `QnAFeedbackStepAsync` and I have an exception not caught : `System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: Void Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.PromptOptions1..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList1<!0>, Int32,`

Comment: Right, that's due to this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/28.

Comment: BTW, are u sure it's returning multiple answers?

Comment: I updated my libraries, it still doesn't working. Yes, I'm sure that it's returning muliple answers. When I use the QnaDialog as my main dialog, it returns multiple answers, as you can see on the second screeshot.

Comment: What do you mean but updating your libraries? The BotBuilder-CognitiveServices package needs to be updated to the latest botbuilder package. Unless you are compiling the code yourself you won't be able to fix the issue.

Comment: I did `Update-package -Reinstall` in Visual Studio on the nuget package manager console

Comment: That's not going to help. The codebase needs to be updated to the latest version and a new package needs to be generated.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure to understand. What should I do for recompiling the librairy and resolve my problem ? Is it possible ? Or should I wait for the next update of the package ?

Comment: You can try it.You need to grab the code from https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/CSharp/Library, update the solution to use the latest version of BotBuilder, recompile and replace the assemblies in your solution with the ones you will get after building it